# Python method object application

Tags: python, function, methods

What are the advantages of having a python method, like `lower()`, being applied to an appropriate object, `s`, via the dot notation (i.e., `s.lower()`) versus a method, like `len()`, being also applied appropriately receiving the object as an argument, e.g. `len(s)` ? If I want to create such a method / function, what are the critical points I should consider choosing the first or the second implementation? Thanks!

Comment: API consistency. Also see http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, If the functionality should be part of an object behavior and it's related only to that object than implement it as a **method** at the class scope, for example, only `str` should have functions like `lower`.

When the function can be applied to a lot of class types like `len` can be applied on `lists` or on `str` than it should be a **function**.